# PC Tune Up, what's involved?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I recently received an offer of a groupon deal where I could get my computer "tuned up" for half price, and I was wondering what do computer shops actually do to tune up a computer?

On my own computer I've done simple things like stop certain unnecessary programs from starting up and running in the background and I like to defrag at least once a month but I'm sure they must do more than that. I've been looking up tune up programs as well, most aren't free, and was wondering what do they do and is it a case where if I hand in my computer the technicians will just run one of these on my computer so I could just cut out the middle man and download one myself?

I assume with these programs it could all be done manually so, as the question states, what's involved?

Comment: This question is impossible for anyone to answer, other than the company who is doing the "tune up."  Only they know what they are going to do.  However, Im sure its not anything you cannot do yourself.

Comment: I know it can all be done by the person but, as the question states, what's involved? And I don't need an exact list of what each company does or something as pedantic as "Company A changed this registry file but company B changed this one instead". I'm wondering how is a "tune up" achieved. It's not impossible, what would you consider a tune up? Has anyone done one themselves? Has anyone bought one of these tune ups and what were the differences? My simple changes affects my start up time quite a bit so I consider that a tune up, if a very simple one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These PC tune-ups are really geared for the computer illiterate as the fixes employed are fairly straight forward and easy. Typically, it's just about cleaning out the spiderwebs and optimizing what you already have.

**Some Examples:**

- Uninstall all bloatware/spyware/malware
- Defragment the HDDs
- In `msconfig`, turn off non-essential programs from starting at boot
- Removing temporary internet files/temporary files (check your user temp directory)
- If using a bulky Anti-Virus Software, recommend a lower resource alternative (MSE/AVG)
- Clean out old drivers that are no longer in use
- Clean out old printing programs that may not be in use (The HP printing suite is possible the closest thing to the anti-christ that I've ever seen)
- Remove GUI boot. Displaying that system logo takes a small amount of resources and you'll see a slight bump in boot-up if you disable it in msconfig
- In `Computer Properties` > `Advanced Settings` > `Performance`, you can disable the majority of the effects and just leave on a couple of the visual cues. It will make the system run much faster without changing the overall look of the system

There are dozens and dozens of small tweaks that you can do to your system that are relatively easy and quick. These services are basically just doing them for you. If you feel confident doing it, then giver.

Comment: Thanks for the concise list. I know what you mean about the HP stuff, I have one of their laptops myself and it came with more HP software than microsoft!